# using Loader.loadBytes - specify SecurityDomain for loaded swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I use Loader.loadBytes to dynamically load a swf into my app (i use this method to load modules into the app). My trouble is that when I want to use ExternalInterface.addCallback to allow js calls on my app. When those functions get called a SecurityError gets thrown because I'm not in the right Security Domain. Trying to set the SecurityDomain of the loaded content via LoaderContext results in another error telling me that SecurityDomain can't be other than null. Is there a way to actually get my modules accessible from JS?

*Note:
I have set in my main ap (the one that instantiates the module controller that loads the modules) the following:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
```

the loading code:

```
var _contextLoader:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
_contextLoader.allowCodeImport = true;
_moduleLoader.loadBytes(moduleBytes, _contextLoader);
```

The error:

```
SecurityDomain 'null' tried to access incompatible context ...
```

Comment: This may help http://forums.adobe.com/message/2348807  which refers you to this page to include your local directory(s): http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html#119065  This worked for some. Another solution is adding to your code: Security.allowDomain("*");  as shown here http://forums.adobe.com/message/4326727

Comment: Another possibility: http://blog.vizio360.co.uk/2009/08/flash-player-trust-file-mac-windows-and-linux/